# How to check whether two input boxes has entered with values or not in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have written a code for displaying the values entered in  two input text boxes in jquery. How to check whether the text boxes are filled with values or not ? I have done with change function to display  the values entered from the text input boxes to be displayed inside the html.I want to validate whether the input boxes is being filled with values in jquery. How to check that ? I have only checked when it is inputted with values.

**Javscript:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").change(function(){

    var startDate = $("#start-date").val();
    var endDate = $("#end-date").val();

    $(".rentdate").html("Rental Date<span> From:"+startDate+" To:"+endDate);

    });
    });

    </script>
```

**html:**

```
<input type="text" id="start-date" name="start" placeholder="Select Date" data-date-format="DD, MM d" class="input-sm form-control"/><span class="date-text date-depart"></span>

<input type="text" id="end-date" name="end" placeholder="Select Date" data-date-format="DD, MM d" class="input-sm form-control"/><span class="date-text date-return"></span>
```

Comment: You will need to  add an if statement for each variable along the lines of if (startDate == "" || startDate == null). Within the if statement then you can display a message stating it is empty.

Comment: So check the length?

Answer (score 2):

Use `input` instead of `change`

```
$("input").on('input',function(){

var startDate = $("#start-date").val();
var endDate = $("#end-date").val();

$(".rentdate").html("Rental Date<span> From:"+startDate+" To:"+endDate);

});
```

HERE is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/sbspLx55/1/)

Comment: Can we use `keyup`?

Comment: i tried your answer with `keyup`..It's working!!suggest difference between `input` and `keyup`

Comment: I told you if you use `keyup` won't work when you use mouse  (to paste or cut) as no key is pressed but input will work

Comment: hi... 
this code will occur if there is no submit button for the submitting the dates inputed...??

Comment: It has nothing to do with submit buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can use if condition to check whether variable is empty or not. Please refer below code for more details.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").change(function(){

        var startDate = $("#start-date").val();
        var endDate = $("#end-date").val();

        if($.trim(startDate) == ""){
            alert("Please enter start date.");
        }else if($.trim(endDate) == ""){
            alert("Please enter end date.");
        }else {
            $(".rentdate").html("Rental Date<span> From:"+startDate+" To:"+endDate);

            });
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: this code will occur if there is no submit button for the submitting the dates inputed...??

Comment: This code will execute when you make changes in input field and then blur from it and also when you paste value in input field. No need of submit button click to execute this code..

Comment: if we donot input any values into the textbox will it show a message to enter the particular input field...

Comment: Yes exactly.. if no value entered then alert message fired.. please enter start date or enter end date .

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = $("#start-date").val();
var endDate = $("#end-date").val();
```

Since You are storing the value of the  text input in a variable ,So you can directly check if the value is empty or not , using comparison like  below

```
if((startDate =="")||(endDate == ""))
{

alert("Please Fill both text Boxes")
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("input").on('input keyup',function(){

   var startDate = $("#start-date").val();
   var endDate = $("#end-date").val();
  
   $("#result").html("Rental Date<span> From:"+startDate+" To:"+endDate);

  });
 });

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="start-date" name="start" placeholder="Select Date" data-date-format="DD, MM d" class="input-sm form-control"/><span class="date-text date-depart"></span>

<input type="text" id="end-date" name="end" placeholder="Select Date" data-date-format="DD, MM d" class="input-sm form-control"/><span class="date-text date-return"></span>


<div id="result"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way is to use regular expressions. And also if you want to immediately show input values then consider event `keyup` instead `change`, cause change event firing only after field lost a focus.
So, said this, your JS might looking as:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("input").keyup(function(){

       var startDate = $("#start-date").val();
       var endDate = $("#end-date").val();
       var regexp = new new RegExp("\\d\\d, \\d\\d \\d"); // based on data-date-format atribute of input fields

       if(!regexp.test(startDate)){ 
         alert("Please enter start date.");
       } else if(!regexp.test(endDate)){
         alert("Please enter end date.");
       } else {
         $(".rentdate").html("Rental Date<span> From:"+startDate+" To:"+endDate);
       }
     });
   });
```

Comment: But if you use Datepicker or any other calendar  UI then event `change` is right, if no, - look reference for calendar plugin.